# There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've done below coding using php5.2 and mySql 5. Now I've upgraded my server to support php 5.3 and mySql 5.1.

```
    do
    {
        if ($this->Result = mysqli_store_result($this->LinkId))
        {
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($this->Result , MYSQLI_ASSOC))
             {
                  $arrRes[] = $row;
             }
             mysqli_free_result($this->Result);
        }
    }while (mysqli_next_result($this->LinkId));
```

Am getting the following error:

> There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method

What should I do?

Comment: @YourCommonSense no that does't works, server got downed while adding. Also forgot to tell this, above code is in do while loop.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Put `mysqli_more_results()` in the `while ()` condition and move the `mysqli_next_result()` inside the loop. I guess this will require a little code reorganisation because you won't want to do that first time through the loop.

Comment: @Hammerite can you able to give example for above code?. It will be helpful to reorganize.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to do something like this.

```
while (true) {
    if ($this->Result = mysqli_store_result($this->LinkId)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($this->Result , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $arrRes[] = $row;
        }
        mysqli_free_result($this->Result);
    }
    if (mysqli_more_results($this->LinkId)) {
        mysqli_next_result($this->LinkId);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For *normal* queries, we can use `$mysql->multi_query`. But how do we get the "multi" version of [`$mysql->prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)?

Comment: That looks like a topic distinct from this question, so maybe ask another question. I don't know whether there is a prepared statement version of `multi_query()` (but note that a single statement can generate multiple result sets, so there is a `more_results()` method on `mysqli_stmt`).