# Why this PHP error occurs: "Strict standards: mysqli::next_result(): There is no next result set."?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I have code, which is basically a copy of a [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)'s code, but for some reason it does not work. Here is the code on php.net:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

**The first change I made was the connection:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "fanfiction");
```

**The second change I made was the queries:**

```
$query = "SELECT first FROM tests;";
$query .= "SELECT second FROM tests;";
$query .= "SELECT third FROM tests;";
$query .= "SELECT fourth FROM tests";
```

**EDIT: The full code with my changes**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "fanfiction");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT first FROM tests;";
$query .= "SELECT second FROM tests;";
$query .= "SELECT third FROM tests;";
$query .= "SELECT fourth FROM tests";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

**The error I get:**

> **Strict standards:** *mysqli::next_result()*: There is no next result set.
>   Please, call *mysqli_more_results()*/*mysqli::more_results()* to check
>   whether to call this function/method in
>   *address* on line *line number*

I searched a solution over the net, and particularly here on StackOverflow, but I did not find helpful solutions. Most of the solutions I found were one of those two:

- In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23569770/1925272),[@Hammerite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340819/hammerite) says to change the loop from `do-while` to `while`. This suggest that php.net's code has a problem in its logic, and I find it very hard to believe. But more importantly, it just does not work for me.
- In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469722/1925272), [@mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) suggests to add a condition in the `while` and change `$mysqli->next_result()` to `$mysqli->next_result() && $mysqli->more_results()`, but this solution do not work quite well. It does indeed removes the error but it omits the last result.

Comment: Isn't your answer in the error message?

Comment: Well, it is not, since I tried to call those functions and it fails, but also because it is php.net's code, so it is very weird that I should add code to theirs for my code to work...

Comment: Their examples don't assume that you are utilizing strict standards in most cases. The answer is in the error message.

Comment: What do you mean? It fails how? Once you have figured it out feel free to fix the code sample on php.net https://edit.php.net/?project=PHP&perm=en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: It is actually the second solution I mentioned. It does eliminate the error, but eventually omit the last result...

Comment: Arew you sure about that?

Comment: Yes, very sure. Can I put a screen print or somthing like that?  And why people vote this question down? :(

Comment: Put your actual problem code in your question because it just works ™... https://3v4l.org/p3bZr

Comment: I now edited it with the full code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92754/discussion-between-sipo-and-peehaa).

Comment: You never bail out when `more_results` returns `false`

Comment: @RyanVincent, yes, i tried, and it works just fine.PeeHaa, did not understand you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it with

```
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
```

[sscce](http://sscce.org/):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "localonly", "localonly", "test");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE City (ID int auto_increment, `Name` varchar(32), primary key(ID))') or die($mysqli->error);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO City (`Name`) VALUES (?)") or die($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $city) or die($stmt->error);
foreach(range('A','Z') as $c) {
    $city = 'city'.$c;
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if (!$mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    trigger_error('multi_query failed: '.$mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
else {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("'%s'\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
}
```

prints

```
'localonly@localhost'
-----------------
'cityU'
'cityV'
'cityW'
'cityX'
'cityY'
```

without warnings/notices.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! it works! But why `$mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result()` works fine and `$mysqli->next_result() && $mysqli->more_results()` omite the last result? Why the order is important?

Comment: It's the wrong oder of functions even if you only consider semantics ;-), first "is there more" then "get me more". If you do it the other way round this is what will happen for the last set: next_result() will activate the last result set and then of course more_results() will signal "no more result sets" and since it's a logical-and and one of the operands is false -> do-while-loop exists without handling the last set.